# The office dialogue. I don't get it the sentence "You go to the bathroom for forty-five minutes and...everything changes."

Tags: meaning

I am learning English watching American sitcom, *The Office*.
While I am watching season9 episode 18(Promos), I found some expression like below and I don't know what it exactly means. Please help me if anybody know this drama or know the meaning of this sentence.

> (The workers are watching their documentary promos.)
>
> Announcer: The workers. The lives. The loves. The people. The paper. 
>   The Office: An American Workplace. Coming soon on WVIA.
>
> ***Kevin: Whoa! You go to the bathroom for forty-five minutes and...everything changes.***
>
> (Scene changed and interview with Kevin)
>
> Kevin: This is a documentary? Oh! I always thought we were like specimens in a human zoo.

The bold part is implicative expression? or just Kevin said after going to the bathroom, everything changed?

Comment: A TV show such as *The Office* is  a comedy, not a drama. It is also called a  '[sitcom](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sitcom)', which is short for 'situation comedy'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### My interpretation

Kevin said he thought they were like specimens in a human zoo, which means he didn't even realize they were getting filmed all along. Thus, in the 45 minutes he was in the bathroom, a whole documentary about them was filmed and published.

I could be wrong though, as the context determines everything. I'm rewatching it and am in the early season 9, I'll get you updated once I see the scene again !

Comment: *"which means he didn't even realize they were getting filmed all along"* - But if he *always* thought they were specimens in a zoo doesn't that mean he did think they were all being watched?

Comment: He knew they were being watched but didn't know it was for a documentary, hence the surprise when seeing the ad for the said documentary after coming back from the bathroom.

Answer (score 5):

> Kevin: Whoa! You go to the bathroom for forty-five minutes
>   and...everything changes.

The pattern of this sentence is:

You {are busy with something} {briefly} during which time {something dramatic or significant occurs}

**You turn your back for a minute, and the whole place is on fire!**

**You take your eyes off the little rug-rat for fifteen seconds, and he's under the sink with his face and hands covered in Comet cleanser!**

The humor is that "45 minutes" occupies the "briefly" slot. In the typical American workplace, a 45-minute toilet break would be considered rather a *long* break from work. Kevin's nonchalance about the time suggests he's a regular shirker who is clueless about his own shirking.

**You take your eyes off the little rug-rat for *fifteen minutes*, and he's under the sink with his face and hands covered in Comet cleanser!**

This statement, with its "for fifteen minutes", would be a comical way of letting the speaker reveal himself or herself to be a lackadaisical parent or babysitter.